# Excel VBA for Switching Style on and off on user selected page in a locked database

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection

I have a database where the user can select one of 17 different pages. Once the page is selected, I need to highlight the part of the page where the user can enter data (switch Style on). Once the user has completed entering the data, the form is then converted to pdf and sent as an attachment in an email, and the style needs to be switched off before the conversion starts.

First, I have this code set when the workbook opens

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Rem Using Sheet instead of Worksheet to care for Charts in the workbook if any
Dim Sht As Object

        'Prevent Computer Screen from running
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
        
    With ThisWorkbook
        For Each Sht In .Sheets
            With Sht
                .Unprotect Password:="Password"
                
        End With: Next
        
    
        With .Sheets("Menu")
            Activate
            Application.Goto .Cells(1), 1
    
    End With: End With
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        For Each Sht In .Sheets
            With Sht
                
                .Protect Password:="Password", _
                    DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, _
                    Scenarios:=True, UserInterFaceOnly:=True
        End With: Next
         
    End With
    
    InputStyleRestore

        'Allow Computer Screen to refresh 
         Application.ScreenUpdating = True
         
         
    End Sub
```

This leads to the sub routine *InputStyleRestore*

```
Sub InputStyleRestore()

        'Prevent Computer Screen from running
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
  With ThisWorkbook
    For Each Sht In .Sheets
        Sht.Unprotect Password:="Password"
    Next: End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Input")
        .Interior.Color = 10079487
        .Font.Color = -9027777
    
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook
        For Each Sht In .Sheets
            With Sht
                .Protect Password:="Password", _
                DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, _
                Scenarios:=True, UserInterFaceOnly:=True
    End With: Next: End With
  
        'Allow Computer Screen to refresh 
         Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Now I have a routine where depending on which page the user selects creates a specific form into a pdf and email

```
Sub PartialPrintFamForm()

Dim FTW As Long
Dim myVariable As String
Dim IsCreated As Boolean
Dim i As Long
Dim PdfFile As String, Title As String
Dim OutlApp As Object
        
' Employee Name as Title
  Title = Range("E21")

    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Caledonian Road Fam Form" Then
        myVariable = Sheets("Caledonian Road Fam Form").Range("R21").Value
        Sheets("Data Input").Range("B1310").Value = WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Caledonian Road Fam Form").Range("O21").Value, Sheets("Data Input").Range("B1:B1000"), 0)
        FTW = Sheets("Data Input").Range("B1310").Value
        Sheets("Data Input").Cells(FTW, 25) = myVariable
        MsgBox "The First page only will now print out for you."
            InputStyleClear
        
        
         ' Define PDF filename
  PdfFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
  i = InStrRev(PdfFile, ".")
  If i > 1 Then PdfFile = Left(PdfFile, i - 1)
  PdfFile = PdfFile & "_" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".pdf"
 
  ' Export activesheet as PDF
  With ActiveSheet.Range("A1:T33")
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PdfFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
  End With
 
  ' Use already open Outlook if possible
  On Error Resume Next
  Set OutlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
  If Err Then
    Set OutlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    IsCreated = True
  End If
  OutlApp.Visible = True
  On Error GoTo 0
 
  ' Prepare e-mail with PDF attachment
  With OutlApp.CreateItem(0)
   
    ' Prepare e-mail
    .Subject = "Familiarisation Certificate for " & Title
    .To = "Name@Domain.uk" ' <-- Put email of the recipient here
    .CC = "Name@Domain.uk" ' <-- Put email of 'copy to' recipient here
    .Body = "Hi," & vbLf & vbLf _
          & "The Familiarisation report is attached in PDF format." & vbLf & vbLf _
          & "Regards," & vbLf _
          & Application.UserName & vbLf & vbLf
    .Attachments.Add PdfFile
    .Display
    
    ' Try to send
    On Error Resume Next
    '.Send
    Application.Visible = True
    If Err Then
      MsgBox "E-mail was not sent", vbExclamation
    Else
      MsgBox "E-mail successfully sent", vbInformation
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
   
  End With
 
  ' Delete PDF file
  Kill PdfFile
    
 
  ' Release the memory of object variable
  Set OutlApp = Nothing
 
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1:T33").PrintOut
        Range("O21,O28").ClearContents
       

    End If

If ActiveSheet.Name = "Arsenal Fam Form" Then
        
        myVariable = Sheets("Arsenal Fam Form").Range("R21").Value
        Sheets("Data Input").Range("B1310").Value = WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Arsenal Fam Form").Range("O21").Value, Sheets("Data Input").Range("B1:B1000"), 0)
        FTW = Sheets("Data Input").Range("B1310").Value
        Sheets("Data Input").Cells(FTW, 9) = myVariable
        MsgBox "The First page only would print, but has temporarily been disabled during testing."
        InputStyleClear
        
        
               ' Define PDF filename
  PdfFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
  i = InStrRev(PdfFile, ".")
  If i > 1 Then PdfFile = Left(PdfFile, i - 1)
  PdfFile = PdfFile & "_" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".pdf"
 
  ' Export activesheet as PDF
  With ActiveSheet.Range("A1:T33")
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PdfFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
  End With
 
  ' Use already open Outlook if possible
  On Error Resume Next
  Set OutlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
  If Err Then
    Set OutlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    IsCreated = True
  End If
  OutlApp.Visible = True
  On Error GoTo 0
 
  ' Prepare e-mail with PDF attachment
  With OutlApp.CreateItem(0)
   
    ' Prepare e-mail
    .Subject = "Familiarisation Certificate for " & Title
    .To = "Name@Domain.uk" ' <-- Put email of the recipient here
    .CC = "Name@Domain.uk" ' <-- Put email of 'copy to' recipient here
    .Body = "Hi," & vbLf & vbLf _
          & "The report is attached in PDF format." & vbLf & vbLf _
          & "Regards," & vbLf _
          & Application.UserName & vbLf & vbLf
    .Attachments.Add PdfFile
    .Display
   
    ' Try to send
    On Error Resume Next
    '.Send
    Application.Visible = True
    If Err Then
      MsgBox "E-mail was not sent", vbExclamation
    Else
      MsgBox "E-mail successfully sent", vbInformation
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
   
  End With
 
  ' Delete PDF file
  Kill PdfFile
  
   
  ' Release the memory of object variable
  Set OutlApp = Nothing
 
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1:T33").PrintOut
        Range("O21,O28").ClearContents
        
        
    End If

    InputStyleRestore
    Sheets("Familiarisation").Select
    ThisWorkbook.Save
        
End Sub
```

I am trying to get *InputStyleClear* to clear just the active page that has been selected. If I use the same routine as *InputStyleRestore* to clear the Style, I find that the page that is converted to pdf & email is always the very last page in the workbook, and not the page originally selected. I tried to see if I could just get *InputStyleClear* to clear the active page with this code

```
Sub InputStyleClear()


        'Prevent Computer Screen from running
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
        
  
    With ActiveSheet.Name
            .Unprotect Password:="Password", _
                DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=False, _
                Scenarios:=False, UserInterFaceOnly:=False
             
    End With
    
    With ActiveSheet.Styles("Input")
            .Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            .Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Borders(xlLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
            .Borders(xlRight).LineStyle = xlNone
            .Borders(xlTop).LineStyle = xlNone
            .Borders(xlBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
            
    End With
    
    With ActiveSheet.Name
        
                .Protect Password:="Password", _
                DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, _
                Scenarios:=True, UserInterFaceOnly:=True
    End With                  
  
        'Allow Computer Screen to refresh
         Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

but it crashes on line **.Interior.Pattern = xlNone**. It seems that the *InputStyleClear* routine works when run on a loop to clear all pages ending up with showing the wrong page, but will not work if trying to unlock a single active page. Any ideas how to achieve what I am looking for would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using colons is not best practice. Placing `End With: Next` on the same line destroys indentation and thereby destroys the readability you probably aim to enhance. `End With` must be on the same indent level as its `With` statement. `Next` must be on the same indent level as its `For` statement, **especially** if you drop the identifier, which is not recommended practice, either. `Next Sht` provides required clarity if there is more than one `For` in a procedure.

Comment: Work on your protection. On Workbook_Open protection is lifted and re-instated with `UserInterfaceOnly = True` for all sheets, including ChartSheets as you point out. If you have a problem accessing any sheet thereafter your protection setting doesn't work as it's supposed to. And if your protection setting works just fine you wont need to lift and reset protection every time you access a sheet.

Comment: Get rid of all references to `ActiveSheet`. Never use it - it's dangerous and misleading. Instead use code like `Dim MySheet As Worksheet: Set MySheet = Worksheets("Caledonian Road Fam Form"): InputStyleClear MySheet` and `Private Sub InputStyleClear(MySheet As Worksheet)`. If you always specify the sheet you mean you will avoid copying a sheet to PDF that you didn't intent to copy.

Comment: Procedure `InputStyleClear` has a lot of problems, I could not test it basically because it does not run. Line: `With ActiveSheet.Name` (twice) this statement is incorrect, it should be `With ActiveSheet`, however I strongly suggest to create an Object variable instead of using `Activesheet`, there is plenty of documentation about why `ActiveSheet` should be avoided. Line: `With ActiveSheet.Styles("Input")` This is also incorrect as the `Styles` are located at `Workbook` level. Perform those correction and try to run your code.

Comment: Have you tried using two Styles, instead of constantly modifying the styles.

Comment: @Variatus - Thank you for the quick reply, I have cleaned up the code in the Sub routine `Workbook_Open()` as you suggested. I am a bit confused by your suggestion of `Set MySheet = Worksheets("Caledonian Road Fam Form")`. There are 17 different pages with different names (I showed 2 of them in the example above), so how would `MySheet` know which page had been selected?

Comment: For procedure `InputStyleClear` I suggest to have the worksheet as an input parameter, something like `Sub InputStyleClear(WshTrg as worksheet)`

Comment: @EEM - I was hoping to be able to have styles highlight the active cells when looking at the page for users to see, but when it came to creating pdf's, emails and printing the form, the style highlights would not appear. Which was why I was trying to switch them on and off. If there is a better way, I am all for it. My skills unfortunately are not up to the level required to figure out how to go about it. Most of what I have achieved is through searching for answers online and trying to amend code found online to do what I want it to do!

Comment: Do you know how to create an style?

Comment: @EEM - How would the 2 styles work? Wouldn't it still be switching between the two styles instead of switching them on or off, which seems to me to be doing the same thing? Or does the coding work in a completely different way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224647/discussion-between-eem-and-ian-martin).

Comment: Not really. I found someone who had coding for creating styles, and borrowed that for my purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to create two Styles and apply each as required before and after printing the PDF's. This will eliminate the need to modify the `Workbook` `Styles` and protect and unprotect the worksheets.

Also replace `ActiveSheet` with object variables:

```
Dim Wsh As Worksheet
Set Wsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Caledonian Road Fam Form")
```

Suggest to name the Styles something like *"Users"* and *"UsersPdf"*

*"UsersPdf"* to be applied before printing the PDF's

```
Wsh.Range("O20,P20,O28,P28").Style = "UsersPdf"
```

*"Users"* to be applied after printing the PDF's

```
Wsh.Range("O20,P20,O28,P28").Style = "Users"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will make the changes when I get back to work tonight. I will also have to brush up on converting ActiveSheet to Object Variables!